# Как передать параметр/переменную в подключаемый скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Подключаем скрипт:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

как сделать, чтоб в него можно было передать переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через глобальную переменную

Comment: В смысле добавить глобальную переменную до этого подключения?

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov Да

Comment: не, не, не, глобальные переменный - это зло, наверное, главный постулат js

Answer (score 3):

гуру js могут сказать, что это говнокод и/или велосипед:

```
function getParams(selector){
    var src = $(selector).attr("src").split("?");    
    var args = src[src.length-1]; // выбираем последнюю часть src после ?
    args = args.split("&"); // разбиваем параметры &
    var parameters = {};
    for(var i=args.length-1; i>=0; i--) // заносим параметры в результирующий объект
    {
        var parameter = args[i].split("=");
        parameters[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

для примера:

`<script id="script" type="text/javascript" src="script.js?arg1=abc&arg2=xyz"></script>`

вызов функции `getParams("#script")` вернёт `{"arg2":"xyz","arg1":"abc"}`

Comment: ДА это круче глобальной переменной :)

Comment: Глобалки тащат.

Answer (score 1):

В HTML5 можно проще через **data-src**...

в HTML'е:

```
script id="MyLoads" data-src="3334" src="./loads.js" defer
```

в скрипте:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("MyLoads")
var keys = doc.dataset.src
alert('Йохохо = ' + keys)
```