# GET переменные в JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я загружаю на страницу javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://second/chat/iframe.js?code=11"></script>
```

Как мне в javascript (iframe.js) получить переменную code? Желательно кроссбраузерно, можно с использованием jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Как передать параметр/переменную в подключаемый скрипт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116889/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82#answer-container-116924)

Comment: супер спасибо всё работает!