# Как передавать параметры в скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Нужно в скрипт передавать данные в таком виде:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="скрипт.js?data=id1:price1,id2:price2,id2:price2,idN:priceN&order=id"
</script>
```

Как в него можно передавать эти параметры?

Comment: @Visman Этот пример видел, но не разобрался как в конечном итоге вызывать. Функция просто возвратит параметры или сразу и произойдет подстановка в скрипт?

Comment: Самостоятельно подстановки не будет. Нужно вызвать функцию. А еще хорошо бы дополнить ту функцию, чтобы можно было параметры конкретного скрипта выдергивать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно так можно сделать то что вы хотели:

Допустим у нас прикрепляется вот этот скрипт:

```
<script src="http://path.to/widget.js" data-width="200" data-height="200">
```

А это сам код в скрипте который берет наши параметры `data-width` и `data-height`:

```
<script>
function getSyncScriptParams() {
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
     var scriptName = lastScript;
     return {
         width : scriptName.getAttribute('data-width'),
         height : scriptName.getAttribute('data-height')
     };
}
</script>
```

А это другой вариант:

```
<script src="http://path.to/widget.js" class="2 5 4"></script>

var params = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
query = params[0].classList;
var param_a = query[0];
var param_b = query[1];
var param_c = query[2];
```

Comment: Сделайте примерно так `src="скрипт.js?data=id1:price1,id2:price2,id2:price2,idN:priceN&order=id"` как автор вопроса просит. Хотя, это уже сделано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/116924/186083

Comment: @Visman Если вы приведете реальный пример того что разработчику мешает дать параметры не так как именно в вопросе написано, то я приведу и этот пример.

Comment: Я вам уже один раз писал, что вы вопросы не читаете, повторять больше не буду, а то опять меня тут обвинят во всех смертных грехах :)

Comment: Так мне нужно не доставать, а передавать параметры. Или я что-то не так понял? :)

Comment: @Visman Ваше право все это)))

Comment: @NikitaBorisov Вот передать можно и по тому как вы писали, и по моему, но где вы хотите эти параметры использовать? в том же скрипте верно? а в скрипте уже надо эти параметры достать, и мои примеры для этого.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Использовать их буду уже не я. Я просто не понимаю как их передавать. Есть скрипт `<script type="text/javascript"
src="скрипт.js?</script>`, есть переменная `data=[{id: 1, price: 111}, {id:2, price: 222}]`, и как вот эти данные из `data` подставить в правильном виде в скрипт?

Comment: @NikitaBorisov А их только 2 или много? и еще откуда берутся эти значения?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan вы имеете в виду сколько объектов в массиве? Из базы данных.

Comment: @NikitaBorisov и зачем манипулировать ими в `js` а не в `php`, И еще если вам все таки нужен на `js`, то вообще то для этого используют `ajax`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Ну вот такая задача. Я потому и спрашиваю как, потому что не знаю :)

Comment: @NikitaBorisov Это уже глобальный вопрос, мы здесь не можем дать целый код страницы с фронтендом и бекендом, еслы вы как то сделайте на `php` или на `ajax` и там будут проблемы обращаетесь

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan А как правильно это все на `ajax` называется? Чтобы погуглить хотя бы :)